# VS TS Build exclude subdirectories in minmatch

Tags: azure-devops, build-process, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, minimatch

I have a Delete Files task in VS TS Build, whose goal is to delete one file at the root of a Source Folder. The minimatch script I have does indeed delete the file correctly, but it also traverses all of the sub folders of the Source Folder directory also looking for a match, which wastes build time. I just want to delete this one file and stop the task.

Here is what I have (simplified for this example):

[image]

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behavior for `Delete Files` task. This task find all files and then match the patterns by default.

As an alternative, you could use `Powershell` task to write a script to delete the file:

```
Remove-Item –path c:\temp\MyFileName.txt
```

Comment: Yes, this is a good approach for what I need and solves the issue. Thanks!